# Interceptor is not triggered when bonded annotation has parameters

Tags: kotlin, annotations, interceptor, quarkus

I have the following annotation bounded with the following interceptor

```
@Target( AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@InterceptorBinding
annotation class NamesAllowed(vararg val values: String)
```

```
@ScopesAllowed("")
@Priority(9)
@Interceptor
class NamesAllowedInterceptor {

    @Inject
    var jwt: JsonWebToken? = null

    @AroundInvoke
    fun intercept(ic: InvocationContext): Any {
        // some logic
        return ic.proceed()
    }
}
```

The annotation is used to extract a custom claim and check a list of names from an incoming JWT

```
@GET
    @Path("/identifier")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RequestScoped 
    @ScopesAllowed("some_scope")  <--- 
    fun getMyCoolResource(): Response {
        // some logic executed
       return Response.ok()
        }
```

**Problem**

The NamesAllowedInterceptor#intercept is never triggered.

When I define my annotation without parameters:

```
@Target( AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@InterceptorBinding
annotation class NamesAllowed
```

The NamesAllowedInterceptor#intercept is triggered. =s

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Your interceptor only applies to `@ScopesAllowed("")`. It doesn't apply to `@ScopesAllowed("anything-else")`.

It looks like you need the annotation member's value to be ignored during interceptor resolution. For that, you need to annotate the annotation member with `@Nonbinding`.

Not sure if this is the correct Kotlin syntax, but it should look like this:

```kotlin
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@InterceptorBinding
annotation class ScopesAllowed(@Nonbinding vararg val values: String)
```